# Запрет изменения позиции contenteditable при добавлении строки

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Как запретить для contenteditable изменять свою верхнюю позицию при расширении числа строчек?

http://jsfiddle.net/jgk4q859/

```
;
```

(для примера вводите дополнительный текст в div, чтобы появилась новая строка и элемент изменит свою позицию, хотя по идее должен стоять на месте).

--
Без поворота отлично расширяется вниз. Но как сделать чтобы при повороте элемент расширялся вверх?

Comment: `transform-origin: 50% 0;`

Comment: @br3t большое спасибо, это работает.  Это помогло во всех случаях, кроме вот такого: http://jsfiddle.net/rcjz188x/ Тут если добавлять текст, который будет за краем родительского контейнера, то блок с текстом начнёт смещаться, а этого не хотелось бы...